# coloring by number android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, flood-fill

I am trying to implement coloring by numbers. I need to be able to fill it with color with one click on the path. At the same time, it is important that the colors will be predetermined. In fact, the user will just need to select the desired number on the panel and click on it on the screen. I don't understand how to do it.

I looked at various options for regular coloring, where you can choose a color and fill the area. Something like `floodFill` and the like. It doesn't suit me.

I am attaching an example image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3URsJ.jpg)

Comment: You have to do it with multi layers images. each layer has a background and user can change the clicked layer background.

Comment: Each part of picture that can fill with a color is a layer. To do coding this you can use a loop with  number of layers on a picture, in each cycle of loop add an ImageView to main layout and load a frame to ImageView and save it (ImageView) to an array. maybe need you explain more.

Comment: i.e. do I need the source image? That is, png or jpeg formats will not work here? I need something like psd?

Comment: no, it's mean that you need vector image file like svg